# Which Database is my ASP NET MVC 3 CodeFirst Project using?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I need to find out, which database is used by default when I create a MVC3 project with EF 4.3 using the Code First approach. 
I have not entered any connection information in the Web.config, the application is working , but I cannot find any related data in my local SQL 2008 Server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Express server in your local machine by default, you can also change the connection via DbContext constructor or web.config file.
Following two links will help you to understand how EF connect database

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks!
I was now able to change it to another database. How could I have connected to the SQL Express DB? Is Visual Studio abled to do so?

Comment: no, if you don't have any connection information in your application, EF connect the local sql express and create the database which name is the same as your namespace + your db context class name. When it comes to SQL Express, it is installed automatically when you installed VS.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Express will be used by default.
Check your AppData folder to find your database file.

Comment: That's where I looked, and there only appeared the ASPNETDB.MDF, which is used for the Membership and Role providers.
I had to add a SQL Database manually to see it in App_Data.